# Ubuntu 22.04 xRDP issue Oh no! something has gone wrong

Tags: xrdp

After upgrading our virtual machine from Ubuntu version 20.04 to 22.04, we have issues when connection with xRDP protocol. When connected to the desktop, we got the error message `Oh no! Something has gone wrong`.

Please find below some output:

```
systemctl status xrdp  
● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-03-18 07:19:15 UTC; 20min ago 
Docs: man:xrdp(8) man:xrdp.ini(5) Main PID: 877 (xrdp) Tasks: 1 (limit: 9508) Memory: 1.7M 
CPU: 17ms CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service └─877 /usr/sbin/xrdp

Mar 18 07:19:13 vm-euw-jump-PWhirn-01 xrdp[828]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 4 
Mar 18 07:19:14 vm-euw-jump-PWhirn-01 xrdp[828]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0 
Mar 18 07:19:14 vm-euw-jump-PWhirn-01 xrdp[828]: [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done  
Mar 18 07:19:14 vm-euw-jump-PWhirn-01 xrdp[828]: [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:3389) 
Mar 18 07:19:14 vm-euw-jump-PWhirn-01 systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Can't open PID file /run/xrdp/xrdp.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitt> 
Mar 18 07:19:15 vm-euw-jump-PWhirn-01 systemd[1]: Started xrdp daemon. 
Mar 18 07:19:16 vm-euw-jump-PWhirn-01 xrdp[877]: [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 877 
Mar 18 07:19:16 vm-euw-jump-PWhirn-01 xrdp[877]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 4 
Mar 18 07:19:17 vm-euw-jump-PWhirn-01 xrdp[877]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0 
Mar 18 07:19:17 vm-euw-jump-PWhirn-01 xrdp[877]: [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
```